# What are the strengths of all the eeveelutions?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

What are the strengths of each of the Eevee evolutions? For example, which of them have the best speed, or highest defense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The base stats of the eeveelutions are spread as follows:

```
Eeveelution  HP    Atk    Def    SpA    SpD    Spd

Vaporeon    130     65     60    110     95     65
Jolteon      65     65     60    110     95    130
Flareon      65    130     60     95    110     65
Espeon       65     65     60    130     95    110
Umbreon      95     65    110     60    130     65
Leafeon      65    110    130     60     65     95
Glaceon      65     60    110    130     95     65
Sylveon      95     65     65    110    130     60
```

As you can see from the above,

- Vaporeon has the highest HP stat;
- Flareon has the highest Attack stat;
- Leafeon has the highest Defense stat;
- Espeon and Glaceon have the highest Special Attack stat;
- Umbreon and Sylveon have the highest Special Defense stat;
- Jolteon has the highest Speed stat.

Comment: Nice work collating these, really shows the breakdown well :)

Comment: @viper_sb Do your research before approving invalid edits.

Comment: @joetheperson Same to you.

Answer (score 5):

All the Eeveelutions have a base stat total of 525, although that is spread onto different stats as Jerry points out in his answer, therefore 'Best' is not a term I would use when describing the various Eeveelutions. Each has different strengths and weaknesses - different Abilities and movesets and (obviously) different typing that allow any of them to fill different roles at will.

There are currently 8 Eeveelutions:
[image: Eevee and the Eeveelutions]
([Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eeveelution))

In terms of competitive play, [Smogon](http://www.smogon.com/) has some good analyses for Black/White, and is slowly getting there with X/Y builds & movesets.

You can find the Black/White analyses here, although do note that some of these are slightly out of date:

- [Flareon](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/flareon)
- [Jolteon](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/jolteon)
- [Vaporeon](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/vaporeon)
- [Espeon](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/espeon)
- [Umbreon](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/umbreon)
- [Leafeon](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/leafeon)
- [Glaceon](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/glaceon)

Here's the current [Sylveon](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/sylveon.3489921/) thread as well, although note that nothing has been finalised as of yet.

However the ones I've used & found most useful are:

### Vaporeon

Although the nerf to Rain in Pokemon X/Y hampers strategies involving the Hydration Ability (status heal under rain, works great coupled with Rest), Vaporeon still makes a splash as a Tank/Healer with it's High HP & Defense and access to Wish (Egg move) and Protect. It also has a decent movepool to choose from including Surf and Hydro Pump, although I've had great success with Scald (gotta love that 30% Burn chance) and Ice Beam. Water Absorb is still a viable Ability, and works well as a switch-in to an enemy Surf/Hydro Pump, on in a Team environment.

### Glaceon

Slow but powerful in Special Attack. Unfortunately Ice isn't the best typing defensively, It only resists itself and is weak to Fire, Fighting, Rock and Steel, which are common on many teams. Blizzard or Ice beam are a given, with Signal Beam or Shadow ball for coverage. The other two moves I'm currently running with are Wish and Protect. Wish is probably not the best move on Glaceon, simply becase it doesn't have the Speed or defense to pull it off, but Protect has worked fairly well.

### Jolteon

Great Speed and Special attack, and OK Special Defense, but not much Physical Defense to speak of. It's ability Volt Absorb allows it to switch into enemy Electric moves like Thunder, absorbing them as health. I'm using Thunderbolt, Signal Beam, Volt Switch and Substitute, although I've found that I rarely use Substitute. Going off of the Smogon page for Black/White, a possible replacement would be Hidden Power Ice

The rest I haven't used, although like I mentioned earlier you can check out Smogon's Black/White pages for suggestions, although remember that they are for Black/White currently